# Tree compare revision in Eclipse SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I have pending changes in my workspace I can rightclick the project and select "Compare with->Base Revision", which gives me a tree view of all pending changes with the possibility to view each changed file in the diff view.

This is what I would like to have also for older revisions, for example when doing a code review. Select the revision from history view and see all changes, be able to navigate between the files and directly compare them easily without having to select each changed file individually and select compare (which means a new server roundtrip, waiting for the dialog to appear, waiting for the revision to be fetched etc.). Currently this is a very tedious process and I can see that the basic functionality is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the best I could find was right-clicking on the project, "Team->Show History",
then selecting the desired revision from the list and selecting "Compare...", and it will give me the desired view with tree on top and comparison side by side in the bottom.

The "trick" seems to be that it has to be the history of a folder, not a single file, otherwise it will complain that "Operation does not apply to directory". But if I select from a directory history, I can also edit the svn paths to compare to e.g. include the parent folder as well, if the commit contains several projects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SVN plugin in eclipse, I use SVN Repositories perspective in Eclipse (Windows -> Perspective -> Open Perspective). It allows you to select 2 different tags/branches and compare them, i.e you can compare the folders and files in one view where you select files and it shows the difference underneath side by side.

Comment: Is anyone aware of a way to automate this (using a hyperlink for example)?

Answer (score 0):

right click on the file in eclipse IDE, then Compare with -> Latest from Repository